# Google Ads API: Error when executing ga_service.search_stream(my_query) method

Tags: python, api, google-ads-api, google-ads-script

I'm trying to make a call to the Google ADS API through the **ga_service.search_stream(my_query)** method using the **client.get_service("GoogleAdsService")**. However i'm getting the error: *" Version v10 is deprecated. Requests to this version will be blocked."*

I run the **print(google.ads.googleads.VERSION**) code and I get the response that the installed version is v16.0.0 however I passed the version to **GoogleAdsClient** like this: **GoogleAdsClient.load_from_storage("my_file.yaml", version=" v16")**

In response I got the following error: *Specified Google Ads API version "v16" does not exist. Valid API versions are: "v10", "v9"*

I made the same call to the method **GoogleAdsClient.load_from_storage("my_file.yaml", version=" v10")** and **GoogleAdsClient.load_from_storage("my_file.yaml", version=" v9")**

I made the same call to the method **GoogleAdsClient.load_from_storage("my_file.yaml", version=" v10")** and got response: *Version v10 is deprecated. Requests to this version will be blocked*."

When I run **GoogleAdsClient.load_from_storage("my_file.yaml", version=" v9")** I get the response: *google.api_core.exceptions.MethodNotImplemented: 501 GRPC target method can't be resolved*

Can you help me? This issue may be associated with settings on the GoogleAds platform?

Answer (score -1):

Only versions 11, 12 and 13 are valid at the time of writing. Try 13 if you're using the latest client library.